# Penile glans amputation

Tags: penis, amputation, circumcision

A 14year old boy's penis was cut off distally at the glans during circumcision. The piece of the glans was not stored in ice but the boy was immediately send to hospital with a piece to be re-attached. It took the ambulance about 1 hour to reach the hospital. The piece was not re-attached but the admitting doctor said it is no longer viable. How long does the piece survive in not in ice?